# Why one of the circuits in the picture don't work

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to create the following circuit on Rasberry Pi board. The LED is suppose to turn on when the as long as the switch button is pressed and off again when the button is released.

I am making this.

[image]

This one doesn't work:

[image]

but this one does:

[image]

I suspect that I shouldn't connect `GPIO 18` circuit to `R3` and `3.3V`. Instead, I should connect  switch to R3 and 3.3V. But isn't that the same thing (looking at the diagram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffvYxm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No, it is not the same thing. The first picture is wrong and not according to the schematic.

The first picture design will only pull the GPIO down via resistor while another resistor pulls it up via the other resistor. That means when button is pushed, the GPIO pin is only pulled down to half of the 3.3V supply voltage, 1.65V. When button is not pushed, there is single 10k pull-up to keep GPIO pin at 3.3V.

The second picture design is according the schematic so it will work. When button is pushed, the GPIO pin is pulled low via single 10k resistor and button to 0V. When button is not pushed, it is pulled up to 3.3V via the two resistors in series to 3.3V.

Comment: Thanks. Some terminology is new to me. Can you please explain what "pulling down" and "pulling up" means? Also, if it is not too much of hassle for you, can you make a circuit diagram of the wrong set up? It would help me comprehend your explanation. No bother if you would not be able to do so, I appreciate your answer anyhow

Comment: A pull up is a resistor that is connected to a positive voltage, often 3.3 or 5V.  A pull down is typically a resistor connected to ground.  Hence an IO input that has nothing else driving it will be high or low respectively.  As a side-note, it’s the convention in digital electronics that the lowest voltage is called ‘ground’ and is sometimes connected to earth, and other supply voltages are expressed as being positive relative to ground.  It wasn’t always this way, and in analogue electronics it’s not uncommon to have both positive and negative voltages relative to ground.